# Long Running goroutines

Tags: parallel-processing, go, cpu-usage

I have 12 to 13 long running goroutines in my app and they are responsible for some thousand short-lived goroutines come and go.

Other than calling runtime.Gosched() periodically, do I need to consider other things to do in long-running ones?

Note: Currently those long-running ones perform some supervisions on collections of resource every 15 to 30 seconds (and some every some minutes) and then they sleep.

Comment: you shouldn't need to call runtime.Gosched() at all, especially if they're idle most of the time.

Comment: @JimB Thanks; If you have this observation in Go apps under heavy loads then please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @kaveh-shahbazian I'd be curious to see what kind of resource supervisions you perform. Would you mind pasting some code or putting a link the a playground sheet? I ask because every time I used background goroutines, I felt almost forced to send some values in some channels, as the only "safe way" to share data and thus have some usefulness to the main goroutine.

Comment: @Ripounet (I am not sure if I'm doing it right; but in short it works for me beyond my initial expectations. So I let them be there.) Those supervisions are like monitoring last activity of connections for example how much time passed? Maybe my device has a problem so produce some kind of alert. I use old school Mutex for controlling shared state and it works well as long as you use just 1 shared state at a time (using more than 1 shared state with Mutex can easily lead to deadlocks). My synced data are like: var count struct { sync.Mutex; c int64 }. But I use channels more and Amore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no ongoing maintenance needed for goroutines. They're managed by the go runtime, and will continue to run until they return, or the main goroutine exits. You shouldn't even be calling runtime.Gosched() as it's only needed when a routine won't yield itself, but yours spend most of their time sleeping.